# Font issues with NextJS and TailwindCSS (font size changes every time I change pages)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Nextjs reloads the font each time I change the page, making the font move as if it's a bug. I don't know why this happens.

Locally, everything works well, and I don't encounter this type of issue when I navigate between menus.

My layout:

```js
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import Head from "next/head";
import React from "react";

import NavBar from "../common/navbar";
import Footer from "../common/footer";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function Layout({
  children,
  title = "",
  description = "Find and stay updated",
}) {
  const pageTitle = title
    ? `google.net - ${title}`
    : "google.net";
  const metaTags = (
    <>
      <title>{pageTitle}</title>
      <meta name="description" content={description} />
    </>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <div className={`${inter.className} bg-white`}>
        <Head>{metaTags}</Head>

        <NavBar />

        <div className="mx-auto flex max-w-screen-xl flex-wrap items-center justify-between tracking-wide md:px-4">
          {children}
        </div>

        <Footer />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `public, max-age=0, must-revalidate` value for the `Cache-Control` header for the webfont. This means that for every page request, the font file is redownloaded. This means a website visitor sees a *flash of unstyled text* (FOUT) – when the text uses a fallback system font before the intended font is downloaded and used.

Consider adjusting the `max-age` to some positive number, such as `31536000` for 1 year (a common convention). This allows the downloaded font file to be reused on subsequent pages, thus preventing FOUT.

You do not experience this locally since the font file would be stored on the same machine as the viewing machine, cutting the download time to an insignificant period of time.

Answer (score 0):

**Wongjn:**

You have `public, max-age=0, must-revalidate` value for the `Cache-Control` header for the webfont. This means that for every page request, the font file is redownloaded. This means a website visitor sees a *flash of unstyled text* (FOUT) – when the text uses a fallback system font before the intended font is downloaded and used.

Consider adjusting the `max-age` to some positive number, such as `31536000` for 1 year (a common convention). This allows the downloaded font file to be reused on subsequent pages, thus preventing FOUT.

You do not experience this locally since the font file would be stored on the same machine as the viewing machine, cutting the download time to an insignificant period of time.

As per [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/production-checklist#caching):

> Next.js automatically adds caching headers to immutable assets served from `/_next/static` including JavaScript, CSS, static images, and other media.
>
> ```
> Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000, immutable
> ```
>
> `Cache-Control` headers set in `next.config.js` will be overwritten in production to ensure that static assets can be cached effectively.

Since it seems like this is *not* the case for you. Consider checking if there is some other configuration omitted from the question that is affecting the `Cache-Control` header of the font file. The website also seems to be hosted on Netlify, so you may wish to review the site host configuration for any caching headers being overridden by the host: https://docs.netlify.com/routing/headers/